# How to catch SOAP error

Tags: php, soap

I'm running a SOAP call which in SOAPUI returns

[image]

Code:

```
$client = new SoapClient($url, array('exceptions' => true)); 
try {
    $a = $client->method($app, $key, array(
        'id' => 1,
    ));  
} catch (SoapFault $soapFault) {
    die('caught!');
}
```

The code never ends up in the `catch` block, I can't get past the method() call. How can I properly handle this error?

Comment: Try a `catch(Exception $soapFault) { var_dump(get_class($soapFault)); }` so you can see which exception type you have to catch.

Comment: You're better off echoing the caught exception, it will have diagnostic data in it regarding the failure.  As it has a __toString implementation, all you need to do is echo $soapFault; in your catch block.  Also, just for debugging, try catch Exception instead of catch SoapFault. I wouldn't recommend it for live but if it helps figure out what's going on then it's useful.  Also, if PHP is configured to log errors, look in the error log (or tail it during script execution)